# Generating ECDH keys using python and secp384 curve in python

Tags: python-3.x, security, elliptic-curve, ecdh

private key pairs and I am trying to generate ECDH keys and I am trying to find a python library to help me do that, Can someone help me if there is any python library out there?

Comment: Questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Anyway I found the answer in the cryptography module of python, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python's [Cryptography](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/ec/) package helped me to achieve this.